# How to test Suggested Tests? List is empty

Tags: xdb

I'm doing some testing for our client on my local environment but I can't see any suggested tests.
I've inspected the sitecore_suggested_test_index and it contains documents.

Anyone has an idea why it is empty? Or knows a way to force suggested tests in the list?

[image]

Comment: what version of Sitecore do you have?

Comment: I'm using SC8.2 U3